# Questions specific to programming issues

Tags: discussion, support

Even after reading the FAQ, I'm still asking myself:

Are questions specific to programming/coding issues **allowed** on magento.se, or are they not (and should be migrated to stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 5):

***I'd hope that they are valid here.***

Magento SE should cover a scope of questions through the different abstraction layers.

1. Server configuration
2. Coding/programming
3. Store administration

If we moved `1.` to Server Fault, `2.` to Stack Overflow - then all we'd be left answering trivial questions for store owners, eg.

> How do I add a product?
>   How can I change a category picture?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking. I don't know, if it's intended to simply have two places, where one can ask Magento coding questions (magento.se and magento* tags on stackoverflow), or if it's thought for configuration questions of store owners only. If it's the former, imo the FAQ should state that more clearly, i.e. in a way like the [FAQ of wordpress.se](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) does it.